capture deleted rows count in a variable from mysql table using bash script
I am trying to capture the number of deleted rows from mysql table from a bash script using --execute option, and it seems to be not working. I have gone through some questions where it mentions using -vv options, it works but not as expected. I used various combinations of -vvv --silent and --skip-column-names with mysql command and awk and sed as well but nothing seems to work.
MySQL Client is mysql  Ver 8.0.39 for Linux on aarch64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
How to get number of rows deleted from mysql in shell script
How to get number of rows affected, while executing MySQL query from bash?
How can you output UPDATE / INSERT query results when using MySQL -e,--execute?
Here is the code
deleted=$(mysql --login-path=lp1 --init-command="SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0" -vv --silent --skip-column-names db -e "delete from table1 where column1 date_format('2022-04-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') and date_format('2023-03-31 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') order by column1 limit 20;")

echo ${deleted}

The statement deletes certain rows but prints an output like this
-------------- delete from table1 where column1 between date_format('2022-04-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') and date_format('2023-03-31 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') order by column1 limit 20 -------------- Query OK, 20 rows affected --------------  1 row in set Bye

If I add one more line to get the row_count then it gives me -1
mysql --login-path=${LP_wallet_0} -e "select row_count()"

Even if I try row_count() in the same delete query it just appends this line select row_count() -------------- 2 1 row in set Bye
I tried different combinations of --vv --silent --skip-column-names and awk and sed too but I am unable to get the count.

You don't need -vv if you query ROW_COUNT();.
Here's an example I just tested. I have a table mytable in my test schema, the table had 6 rows.
mysql -s -N -e "delete from mytable; select row_count()" test

Output:
6

I used -s for silent, -N for skipping column names, and I made sure to select row_count() in the same session.
Thus it outputs just 6, indicating the number of rows affected. Since the output is simply that result, it's easy to capture without needing to do any parsing with sed or awk.
If you try to query row_count() in a subsequent mysql command, it won't work, because it only reports the number of rows affected by the preceding SQL statement of the same session.

it worked like magic for me @bill. Thanks tons :-D.

@AvinashPawar are you familiar with What should I do when someone answers my question? ?

oops apology, I was too eager get my scripts working and forgot to mark the answer
